# собрать массив за один цикл ? (не зная размера)

Tags: c

Как собрать массив байтов из строки, которая имеет одновременно и латинские, и кириллические символы за один цикл?

Прохожу циклом, проверяю каждый байт на корректность (с кириллической пары байтов делаю один байт, латинский и так один и пытаюсь записать всё в новый массив). Но для того, чтобы это сделать, мне пришлось использовать 2 цикла: первым я проверял на корректность и подсчитывал байты с учетом кириллицы, а вторым уже делал преобразование, предварительно создав массив с определённой в первом цикле длинной.

```
char *arg = "latin-кириллическая string-строка"; 
size_t arg_len = strlen(arg);
if (arg_len > 20000) {
    // error
}
int i = 0, len = 0;
while (i < arg_len) {
    if (!(arg[i] & 0x80)) {
        len++;
    } else {
        /* здесь идут проверки на корректность рус-укр алфавитов и подсчет количества символов (len++ для каждого кириллического символа) */
    }
    i++;
}
char arr[len];
for (i=0; i<arg_len; i++) {
    /* и здесь уже с нужными проверками на кириллицу и латиницу заполнение массива arr */
}
```

В начале я думал просто выделять массив с размером `arg_len`, но потом прикинул, что если строка будет полностью кириллическая, выделять 20000 байт для того, чтобы положить в них около 10000 как-то нецелесообразно.

Есть ли способ собрать за один цикл массив нужно размера? (про malloc и realloc даже не стал писать, так как количество переаллокаций на мой взгляд будет относительно велико, да и по возможности хотелось бы обойтись памятью на стэке, без куч).

Хотелось бы использовать что-то наподобие такого

```
char arr[] = {};
```

Но попытка заполнить в одном цикле такой массив приводит к сегментации. У меня максимум получилось использовать так 30 байт :(

Comment: Заведите сначала большой массив. В конце делайте один реаллок на нужный размер.

Comment: а как узнать этот самый нужный размер?) в этом то и проблема... я уже думал про подобное взять выделить malloc половину arg_len (надеясь что строка кириллическая) и заполнив первый выделенный блок снова узнать остаточный размер, половину и realloc и т.д но это всё равно не 1 realloс...(а если учесть что кириллицы и вовсе может не быть в строке становится грустно от такой реализации).

Comment: исходите из самого плохого варианта - то есть возьмите самую длинную возможную строку

Comment: если исходить из самого плохого варианта что максимум это 20000 байт и почти все они кириллические то около 10000 байт было выделено напрасно(( неужели нет лучше решения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не вижу ничего плохого в двух циклах.
2. `char arr[len];` - ты объявляешь массив в стеке. Нет никакого смысла играться с его размером - он умрёт после выхода из функции, а если ты боишься переполнения стека, так это значит что в худшем случае (все буквы латинские) он у тебя всё равно возможен. Так что объявляй на максимальный размер и всё.
3. Кажется ты байт на завершающий нолик забыл.

Comment: 1) всё-таки 2 цикла больше чем 1 и ресурсов занимает тоже больше..
2) да это я знаю что он в стеке
3) в реализации он есть спасибо. просто вынес кусок кода для примера показать в чем суть...

Comment: в моем случаи память *arg повторно не используется, потому оптимальный способ перезаписать уже выделенный кусочек не используя второй цикл...